# Algorithm to check if there's a vertex where all other vertices are reachable from it.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Let a connected and directed graph $G=(V,E)$. I'm trying to understand a relatively simple algorithm to check if there's a vertex such that any other vertex is reachable from it.

The algorithm is going like this: Look at the "Opposite graph" (edges are at opposite direction). Start a BFS scan from an arbitrary node and find a leaf in the BFS tree. Let's call it $w$.

Now, run from $w$ a BFS scan on the original graph. Check if all vertices were scanned. If so, $w$ is the desired vertex.

I only partially understand why this algorithm works and I'd be glad for an explanation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why, in the opposite graph, the sought vertex must necessarily be a leaf.  Did you include all the conditions of the problem?

Also, have you looked at Minimal Spanning Tree algorithms?

Comment: @avs, it doesn't have to be a leaf, but if there is such a vertex, then one of the leaves of the backwards BFS tree will satisfy it.  This is not an algorithm to find all such vertices.  Also, keep in mind that the leaf they find is not necessarily a leaf in the original graph...

Comment: The leaf they find is certainly not a leaf in the original graph, because in the original graph that vertex will have in-degree 0 (so, not a leaf), and out-degree 1.

Comment: @avs, they might find a leaf in the original graph.  Recall that the first BFS is being done in a graph with all the edges reversed.  So when it is found, it has (at least) one incoming edge.  In the original graph it would have (at least) one outgoing edge.

Comment: @TravisJ, isn't that what I wrote?:)  "out-degree 1"

Comment: @avs, perhaps I misunderstood the meaning of your "certainly not a leaf in the original graph."  I was just pointing out that it could be a leaf in the original graph.  Perhaps the confusion is the definition of a leaf in a directed graph.  To me, it is a leaf if in_degree+out_degree=1.

Comment: @TravisJ, by a leaf in a directed graph I meant in_degree =1 , out_degree = 0.  (A leaf has no outgoing branches.)  I could be wrong about the standard definition, though.